# why update query updated two records everytime?

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm creating one application where i want to store every last time_out details in time_out_history column base on current date for that i created query query is working fine but problem is it is always update whole record

```
EMPLOYEE_ID--       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
TIME_IN--           TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
TIME_OUT--          TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
WORKING_HOUR--      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
PUNCH_DATE--        DATE
TIME_OUT_HISTORY--  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
```

and my query is :

```
 UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY=
  (SELECT pk.TIME_OUT FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME pk WHERE trunc(punch_date)=trunc(SYSDATE))
```

Comment: Normally, you would _**condition**_ the update via the user of `WHERE` clause. In your case, you are updating the whole table since you are not telling the system which records to update (again, via the use of a `WHERE` clause).

Comment: @FDavidov: thanks for reply in where condition i mention that update data if it is found in sysdate

Comment: No. The `WHERE` applies ONLY to finding the value for `TIME_OUT_HISTORY` which could also be NULL in case the condition returns false. The `WHERE` I'm talking about refers to the `UPDATE` command, meaning, defining which records should be updated. As stated, in your current command you are updating all the records. I'll put an answer explaining this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 
  SET T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY= (SELECT pk.TIME_OUT 
                              FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME pk 
                             WHERE trunc(punch_date)=trunc(SYSDATE)
                           ) ;
```

Here, through the inner `SELECT` you are seeking a valid value to be assigned to `T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY`. You may find some value or not, in which case the result of the select would be `null`.

To update only those records that you want to be updated, your command should look something like:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 
  SET T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY= (SELECT pk.TIME_OUT 
                              FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME pk 
                             WHERE trunc(punch_date)=trunc(SYSDATE)
                           )
WHERE T1.<column name> ....
  AND T1.<column name> .... ;
```

The added `WHERE` determines the rules to be used when selecting records from `EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME` that should be updated.

How this makes things clearer to you.

Comment: thank you  yes it is clear  and working perfectly as expect here is new query   UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY=
  (SELECT PK.TIME_OUT FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME PK WHERE TRUNC(PK.PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE))
  where t1.employee_id='73584' and TRUNC(T1.PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)

thank you once again sir

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!